# Количество записей, где встречается определенное значение

Tags: sql, django

столкнулся со следующей проблемой: есть 2 таблицы вида

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    finish_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

class Code(models.Model):
    code_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    correct = models.BooleanField()
    game = models.ManyToManyField(Game)
```

В одной игре может быть несколько кодов с одинаковым code_text. Хочу посчитать в скольких играх встречается каждый правильный код, то есть в идеале должна получиться таблица вида "правильный код - количество игр в которых он встречался", но получается посчитать сколько раз вводился правильный код вообще. Сам дошел вот до такого:

```
SELECT backend_code.code_text, COUNT(backend_game.name) 
FROM backend_code 
JOIN backend_code_game ON backend_code.id=backend_code_game.code_id 
JOIN backend_game ON backend_game.id=backend_code_game.game_id 
WHERE backend_code.correct=true
AND backend_code.code_text IN 
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT backend_code.code_text FROM backend_code 
    JOIN backend_code_game ON backend_code.id=backend_code_game.code_id
    JOIN backend_game ON backend_game.id=backend_code_game.game_id
    WHERE backend_code.correct=true)
GROUP BY backend_code.code_text 
ORDER BY COUNT(backend_game.name) 
DESC;
```

Собственно, в какую сторону читать? 
Не на ORM просто потому что захотелось sql поковырять:)

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью ORM:

```
result = Code.objects.filter(correct=True).values('code_text').annotate(count_game=Count('game'))
```

Если интересен SQL можно посмотреть какой SQL Django сгенерирует для QuerySet:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748295/getting-the-sql-from-a-django-queryset

Answer (score 0):

С возможной поправкой на диалект SQL, должно быть что-то вроде

```
SELECT c.code_text, COUNT(cg.game_id) as gcount
FROM backend_code_game cg 
JOIN backend.code c ON cg.code_id = c.id 
WHERE c.correct = true 
GROUP BY c.code_text
ORDER BY gcount;
```